# How to hide defined constants

Tags: isabelle

When I import theory files which come with defined constants (for recursive functions or definitions) like `f`, how can I hide such a constant in the current theory file? In other words, I want to make sure that `f` is a free variable. I do not want to change the imported files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is exactly the purpose of the `hide_const` command. E.g.,

```
hide_const f
```

will completely remove the defined constant `f` from the current context (and thus make it inaccessible). If you use

```
hide_const (open) f
```

instead, only the base name is hidden (i.e., `f`), but the qualified name (e.g., `A.f` if `f` was defined in theory `A`) still works.

There are similar commands for classes, types, and facts: `hide_class`, `hide_type`, and `hide_fact`. See also [the Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2013/doc/isar-ref.pdf), page 105.