# How to hide multiply defined constants

Tags: isabelle

This questions extends the question [How to hide defined constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254465/hide-a-definition-or-function-free-variable-name).

I import theory `A`, `B`, and `C`, maybe in future also `D`, `E`, ... 
All theories define a function `f`. I want to hide the definition of `f` in my current theory without changing the imported theories. When I write `term f` I get `A.f`. When I add `hide_const (open) f` to my current theory, `A.f` is hidden but now I get `B.f` as `f`. How can I completely hide `f`? 
I need something like `(hide_const (open) f)+`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The versions of function `f` from each theory have separate names (`A.f`, `B.f`, `C.f`), and these must all be hidden separately.

You are allowed to hide multiple names with a single `hide_const` command, though, and this is what I would recommend:

```
hide_const (open) A.f B.f C.f
```

Comment: How can you hide a function? Like say I want to hide natural addition. How can I do?